# index not accepted in simd instructions

Tags: c++, intel, sse, simd

```
for(y=0; y<line; y++){
    base=y*line;
    gx[base]=ptr[base];

    for(x=0; x<line-4; x+4){
        i=base+x;
        prec = _mm_load_ps(&ptr1[i]);
        succ = _mm_load_ps(&ptr2[i]);
        res = _mm_sub_ps(succ,prec);
        _mm_store_ps(&gx[i+1],res);
    }
```

I've an execution error on "_mm_store" why? 
don't accept index i+1; With i is correct

Comment: Surely that error comes with some kind of a message? Also, your inner `for` loop doesn't look right - `x+4` does not increase `x`.

Answer (score 3):

`_mm_store_ps` requires a 16 byte aligned destination address. Use `_mm_storeu_ps` for unaligned stores.